# How to specify network address or ip address in json schema?

Tags: json, types, format, ip, jsonschema

> Which jsonschema type or format should be used for network address(eg: 20.20.0.0/24) and ip (20.20.0.20) which is a part of properties in jsonschema? Does "type" : "string" validate ips?

Answer (score 0):

I assume type:string will not satisfy your requirement. but you can always use **pattern** key to give a pattern of your data.

Ref:
http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.8